# Circuit editor missing from Ask Question page?

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, circuitlab, user-interface

Have we lost the Circuitlab circuit editor feature?  I started asking a question this morning, and the button appears to be missing from the editor.  Maybe it is down for maintenance or such?

[image]

Comment: @VoltageSpike: I see the relevant icon just fine on the main site... It looks like the relevant site setting is only off for this meta site for some reason – I guess it was never enabled on this meta? – though it's enabled on the main site. ...It also looks like the button is visible in the regular editor on the main site, but for some reason it's not visible on the Ask Question page.

Comment: Yeah, I can't see it on the main site anymore either in the ask question page, I don't remember it being on the meta, but it needs to be back on the main site.

Comment: I have a fix for this in a PR, will let you know once it's out.

Answer (score 10):

Fixed now, thanks for the report!

This was a bug I created over 10 years ago. Under specific timing conditions, it was possible for dependencies like the CircuitLab plugin to never start. Those timing conditions apparently never happened until recently (it can come down to something as simple as two files loading in different order), which is why it was never noticed before.

Comment: "This was a bug I created over 10 years ago." – Sounds like an achievement of some kind :D

Comment: @V2Blast Bugs are like wine, they get better with age.

Comment: Thanks for fixing